# Why is the cd command not working in xiki for sublime text 2?

Tags: command-line, sublimetext2, cd, xiki

In xiki for sublime I run this line

```
$cd /Users/my_name
```

and no errors or anything appear. However when I run this command

```
$pwd
```

this is the output I get

```
/Users/my_name/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages
```

It seems like it should be in my home directory. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer. For anyone who is interested, you have to type the directory you are working in above the command. For example

```
/Users/my_name/
    $ls
```